# Jruby does not install runtime dependencies with travis.ci

Tags: ruby, jruby, travis-ci

I am running travis.ci with my https://github.com/JelF/xquery/tree/release/0.2.0
How could i fix it?

In xquery.gemspec i specified `spec.add_dependency 'activesupport', '~> 4.0'` and it works localy with jruby and at travis with mri, but with jruby-9.0.4.0 bundler does not install `activesupport` gem

Complete travis log: https://s3.amazonaws.com/archive.travis-ci.org/jobs/96552234/log.txt

update: i retested master which have passed it previously and problem persist
update2: changed `add_runtime_dependency` to `add_dependency`, no impact

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: update: i retested master which have passed it previously and problem persist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have exactly the same problem. All worked fine up until this week. I just restarted the Travis builds (no code changes) and the jruby builds start to fail because some gems are not installed. It happens on jruby 9.0.1.0 in my case.

And I can repeat it on my own system - unfortunately - after updating rvm to head and installing jruby 9.0.1.0 again. Bundle install/update just won't install the gems listed with add_runtime_dependency or add_dependency.

The latest version of Builder is to blame. If you want to know more about this, go to the issue on [github](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/4157)

To solve this issue, either do not use 1.11.0 of builder or add the following line to the gemspec:

```
spec.platform = Gem::Platform::JAVA if defined?(RUBY_ENGINE) && RUBY_ENGINE == 'jruby'
```

At least for me that worked.